# How to pick dynamic element and how to pick element using aria-label using selenium and python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is webpage snapshot from which I am trying to pick two elements, one is a more button to view hidden options and another is to click on hidden option once visible on click.

```
<div id="ember54" class="artdeco-dropdown artdeco-dropdown--placement-bottom artdeco-dropdown--justification-left ember-view">
    <button aria-expanded="false" id="ember55" class="artdeco-dropdown__trigger artdeco-dropdown__trigger--placement-bottom ember-view 
        pvs-profile-actions__action
        artdeco-button
        artdeco-button--secondary
        artdeco-button--muted
        artdeco-button--2
        
      " type="button" tabindex="0">
        <span aria-label="More actions">More</span>
    
<!----></button>
    <div tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="ember56" class="pvs-overflow-actions-dropdown__content artdeco-dropdown__content artdeco-dropdown--is-dropdown-element artdeco-dropdown__content--justification-left artdeco-dropdown__content--placement-bottom ember-view"><div class="artdeco-dropdown__content-inner">
  
      <ul>
          <li>
              
  <div data-control-name="share-profile" id="ember57" class="pvs-profile-actions__action display-flex align-items-center  artdeco-dropdown__item artdeco-dropdown__item--is-dropdown ember-view" tabindex="0"><!---->
      <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="share-linkedin-icon" class="mr3" size="large"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M23 12l-4.61 7H16l4-6H8a3.92 3.92 0 00-4 3.84V17a4 4 0 00.19 1.24L5.12 21H3l-.73-2.22A6.4 6.4 0 012 16.94 6 6 0 018 11h12l-4-6h2.39z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
    <span class="display-flex t-normal" aria-hidden="true">Share profile in a message</span>
    <span class="a11y-text">Share Mr X’s profile via message</span>
  </div>

          </li>
          <li>
              
  <div data-control-name="save_to_pdf" id="ember58" class="pvs-profile-actions__action display-flex align-items-center  artdeco-dropdown__item artdeco-dropdown__item--is-dropdown ember-view" tabindex="0"><!---->
      <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="download-icon" class="mr3" size="large"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M21 14v5a3 3 0 01-3 3H6a3 3 0 01-3-3v-5h2v5a1 1 0 001 1h12a1 1 0 001-1v-5zm-4-.57V11l-4 2.85V3h-2v10.85L7 11v2.43L12 17z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
    <span class="display-flex t-normal" aria-hidden="true">Save to PDF</span>
    <span class="a11y-text">Save Mr X’s profile to PDF</span>
  </div>

          </li>
          <li>
                
  <div data-control-name="follow" id="ember59" class="pvs-profile-actions__action display-flex align-items-center  artdeco-dropdown__item artdeco-dropdown__item--is-dropdown ember-view" tabindex="0"><!---->
      <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="plus-icon" class="mr3" size="large"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M21 13h-8v8h-2v-8H3v-2h8V3h2v8h8z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
    <span class="display-flex t-normal" aria-hidden="true">Follow</span>
    <span class="a11y-text">Follow Mr X</span>
  </div>


          </li>
          <li>
                        
  <div data-control-name="connect" id="ember60" class="pvs-profile-actions__action display-flex align-items-center  artdeco-dropdown__item artdeco-dropdown__item--is-dropdown ember-view" tabindex="0"><!---->
      <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="connect-icon" class="mr3" size="large"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M14 7a5 5 0 11-5-5 5 5 0 015 5zm-3 7H7a3 3 0 00-3 3v5h10v-5a3 3 0 00-3-3zm9-2V9h-2v3h-3v2h3v3h2v-3h3v-2z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
    <span class="display-flex t-normal" aria-hidden="true">Connect</span>
    <span class="a11y-text">Connect with Mr X</span>
  </div>

<!---->

          </li>
      </ul>
    
</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

where id="emberx" keeps on changing.

I am trying to pick element - `<span aria-label="More actions">More</span>` via

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('artdeco-dropdown artdeco-dropdown--placement-bottom artdeco-dropdown--justification-left ember-view">
    <button aria-expanded="false" id="ember55" class="artdeco-dropdown__trigger artdeco-dropdown__trigger--placement-bottom ember-view 
        pvs-profile-actions__action
        artdeco-button
        artdeco-button--secondary
        artdeco-button--muted
        artdeco-button--2').find_element_by_tag_name('span').click()
```

but it is giving me an error `no such element: Unable to locate element`

Also I am trying to pull element `data-control-name="connect" id="ember60"` but that id also keeps in changing,

this ember# appeared several hundred times on same webpage.

Do you know, how we can handle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below xpath :

```
//span[text()='More']/..
```

and click on it like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()='More']/..').click()
```

and if `emberx` is keep on changing, you may to write this xpath :

```
//div[contains(@id, ember) and contains(@class, 'display-flex align-items-center')][1]
```

or nothing works, you can take all 100's of emberx in a list using `find_elements`

```
for ember in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id, ember) and contains(@class, 'display-flex align-items-center')]")
     print(ember.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey this seems to work but still the issue is `//div[contains(@id, ember) and contains(@class, 'display-flex align-items-center')][1]` clicking on first matched element, although I only have to click when `<span class="display-flex t-normal" aria-hidden="true">Connect</span>` appear, its position can be 2 or 3 or 4 or 5., that's also changing

Comment: You can have a check for `Connect`, like this : 

`if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Connect']")) > 0:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, ember) and contains(@class, 'display-flex align-items-center')][1]").click()`